# How to access multilevel nested Subform to refresh it

Tags: vba, ms-access

How can I access nested subform to refresh it or to bring some controls. Below i pointed out my form structure example.

```
Forms!MainNav!NavigationSubform!frmOrders!sfrmOrders.Refresh
```

I just can't figure out how that referencing thing works. When to use ! and when just Dot. When to prefix with .Form and when to not. Or when to use [] and when not.
I attached also image. In the end I need to refresh just 4th Datasheet form which are nested into 3rd form.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every step but the first, you need to specify that you want the `.Form` property of the subform control:

```
Forms!MainNav!NavigationSubform.Form!frmOrders.Form!sfrmOrders.Form.Refresh
```

Comment: `Forms!MainNav!NavigationSubform.Form.Refresh` works only for me. Still can't access directly to 4th level subform.